# SaltStack - FreeBSD Ports - ports.update

Tags: yaml, freebsd, salt-stack

Why is this state.sls not working?

```
install_ports:
  - ports.update:
    - extract: True
```

When running

```
salt '*' state.highstate
```

I get a return of:

```
SaltMaster:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    ID install_ports in SLS FreeBSD.11_0.ports is not a dictionary
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
root@SaltMaster [~]$
```

I worked according to:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2015.8/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.freebsdports.html

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.ports.html#module-salt.states.ports

Comment: sorry, I meant: Why is this not working:

Comment: install_ports:
  ports.update:
    - extract: True

Comment: Result:           ID: install_ports
    Function: ports.update
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'ports.update' was not found in SLS 'FreeBSD.11_0.ports'
              Reason: 'ports.update' is not available.
     Changes:

Comment: install_ports:
  ports.update:
    - extract: True

Thanks. Unfortunately it is also not working. It throws:

State 'ports.update' was not found in SLS 'FreeBSD.11_0.sync_ports'
Reason: 'ports.update' is not available.

Answer (score 3):

Lines beginning with "-" are items in a YAMl list, and your 'install_ports' line is expecting a dictionary.

Thus, you should change '- ports.update:' to 'ports.update:' to get rid of the error.